# ObservableList<Node> method reference error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8

I am looking at the lambda and javaFX sample project "MaryHadALittleLambda" (https://github.com/steveonjava/MaryHadALittleLambda).

Everything compiles fine except the method

```
private void populateCells(Group root, final SpriteView.Mary mary) {
    // Gratuitous use of lambdas to do nested iteration!
    Group cells = new Group();
    IntStream.range(0, HORIZONTAL_CELLS).mapToObj(i ->
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(i * CELL_SIZE, j * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            rect.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            rect.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            rect.setOnMousePressed(e -> mary.moveTo(new Location(i, j)));
            return rect;
        })
    ).flatMap(s -> s).forEach(cells.getChildren()::add);  // <-- ERROR HERE

    root.getChildren().add(cells);
}
```

as I get an error in Eclipse on the forEach line,

```
The type ObservableList<Node> does not define add(Object) that is applicable here
```

The forEach takes a method reference to an instance method of the *cells* object, which looks perfectly valid to me. If I use the following lambda instead, it works fine :

```
    ).flatMap(s -> s).forEach(r -> cells.getChildren().add((Rectangle) r));
```

So it seems that every features of java 1.8 are compiling safe for this javaFx reference.
My guess is that something is wrong with my version or setup of Java? I am using :

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK version: Kepler Service Release 2
Eclipse Java Development Tools Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2)
```

And using the JRE from this Java version (output from the command line) :

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the MaryHadALittleLambda project in Intellij Idea IU-135.667 (13.1.2) with Java 8b132 (production release).  Idea also marks the `cells.getChildren()::add` reference as an error in the editor, but Idea will still compile and execute the source fine without error.  I cannot explain to you why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be answering my own question by providing some updates:
I contacted the author who suggested I try the java compiler, not eclipse's: building with Ant (and hence using the jdk javac compiler) compiles just fine, and the application runs.

When I looked at the status of java 8 support in eclipse, it seems there are many things to be resolved : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=1.8%20lambda

As @jewelsea pointed, Intellij Idea shows the error but will compile and execute (I assume it uses the jdk-provided javac).

So the answer is : **wait for upcoming updates to eclipse and/or the jdk.** This specific case is easy to work-around.

And the real issue is that `mapToObj` provides a `Stream<Object>`, and the loop will  pass `Object` to the `::add` which expects `Node`instances (as `Rectangle` are).

Answer (score 0):

I have hit the same issue. This must be some kind of bug with type inference in the Eclipse compiler. I found that it also compiles when manually extracting the function within mapToObj:

```
private void populateCells(Group root, final SpriteView.Mary mary) {
    IntFunction<Stream<Rectangle>> mapper = i -> IntStream.range(0,
            VERTICAL_CELLS)
            .mapToObj(
                    j -> {
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(i * CELL_SIZE, j
                                * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
                        rect.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
                        rect.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
                        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                        rect.setOnMousePressed(e -> mary
                                .moveTo(new Location(i, j)));
                        return rect;
                    });
    // Gratuitous use of lambdas to do nested iteration!
    Group cells = new Group();
    IntStream.range(0, HORIZONTAL_CELLS).mapToObj(mapper).flatMap(s -> s)
            .forEach(cells.getChildren()::add);

    root.getChildren().add(cells);
}
```

Comment: Indeed you are right, it works too. The IntFunction<Stream<Rectangle>> provides the type that the Eclipse compiler fails to infer as you suggested.